# databricks-cli: JSONDecodeError when running job in bash script

Tags: json, bash, databricks, databricks-cli

I am trying to run a Databricks job with notebook parameters within a bash script on a Linux server. I am following instructions from the [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dev-tools/databricks-cli.html#jobs-cli) and I have verified that the commands work in terminal.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

### this commands works in terminal but not when running script
databricks jobs run-now --job-id 1 --notebook-params '{"param1":"value1"}'

### this command works fine in terminal and when running script
databricks runs list
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 59 (char 58)
```

What is also interesting is that other `databricks-cli` commands work in that do not require a JSON string argument.

Comment: Try to run the command explicitly with an utf-8 locale: `LANG=en_US.UTF8 databricks jobs run-now --job-id 1--notebook-params '{"param1":"value1"}'`. Does that work?

Comment: I tried adding `export LANG=en_US.UTF8` to script and also tried just adding `LANG=en_US.UTF8` in front of the databricks command and still getting same error

Comment: the script runs on the same host where you run it in terminal, right? (and not in a container or vm, right?)

Comment: Correct I'm running script in the terminal (`./run_script.sh`) and it's the same terminal where I was able to run the commands successfully. They just don't work when I try to execute the commands inside the script.

Comment: Are you running it as another user?

Comment: do you mean another Databricks user? I used my Databricks user token and I am the one who created the Databricks job and notebook

Comment: No, I meant system user. Could be that you run the script with sudo. Otherwise I have not idea, must be a databricks specific problem then. (I thought it could be system related)

Comment: @hek2mgl Sorry but I stupidly didn't include the fact that I was passing a variable to the JSON string and that was the issue all along.

Answer (score 1):

The script I provided in the question was not actually representative of the script I was running.

The script I'm actually running is something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

currentdate=`date +\%Y\%m\%d`
RUNDATE=$(date "--date=${currentdate} - ${stepsize} day" +%Y%m%d)

### this commands works in terminal but not when running script
databricks jobs run-now --job-id 1 --notebook-params '{"param1":"value1", "rundate":"$RUNDATE"}'

### this command works fine in terminal and when running script
databricks runs list
```

and the issue was passing a variable to the JSON.

The working version is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

stepsize=1
currentdate=`date +\%Y\%m\%d`
RUNDATE=$(date "--date=${currentdate} - ${stepsize} day" +%Y%m%d)

echo $rundate 

databricks jobs run-now --job-id 263 --notebook-params '{"param1":"value1", "rundate":"'"$RUNDATE"'"}'

databricks runs list
```